# How Can I get Object Properties from within an Object Anonymous type in C# from LINQ to Entities Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, object

Lets say I have an method which returns an object. I return a new object which contains two properties Sum and Count. When I call this method, How can I retrieve these properties?

```
public static object SomeMethod(){
   using (var context = new MappedTableEntities()){
      return from x in context.SomeMappedTable
                   group x by 1 into g
                   select new
                   {
                       Count = g.Count(),
                       Sum = g.Sum(col => col.someSummableColumn)
                   };
       }
}
```

when I call this function:

```
var obj = SomeClass.someMethod();
```

I do not see the properties exposed and I get a compiler error when I try to retrieve them. How can I expose these members?

```
/*ERROR */
var count = obj.Count;
var sum = obj.Sum;
```

Comment: Just for the record, this is why anonymous types are such a bad idea in most cases. Also, the linked duplicate was the first result of a search for "retrieve properties of anonymous type C#". Perhaps you didn't know that you were creating an anonymous type, but it makes me feel sad when I find a duplicate that quickly :(

Comment: Yeah I didn't know this was a subcategory. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, now you know, and learned two things!

Comment: I have a problem, The solution for the question that this is linked to, does not work for an object return from select new {prop, prop2}. This is form a LINQ to Entity Framework query which was using the Count and Sum Aggregator functions

Comment: @BradleyDotNET can you re-open this?

Comment: Did you try the dynamic or reflection solutions? Its still effectively the same problem. I am considering re-opening it, but would like to know if either of those worked for you. You could always just use a strong type of course, but that doesn't really answer your question (though it may be easier!).

Comment: Yes ive tried them both to no avail. I had to separate the query out into two queries. But this seems inefficient. I would assume it can be done in one query.

Comment: Alright. I re-opened it. I think the answer is really to use a strong type.